# In angular 9, how can I trigger Validators.required for a kendo-dropdownlist that's bound to an array of objects?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, angular-formbuilder

This was working fine when I just had an array of strings instead of objects with the KVP of text/value.  But now the required validator is no longer triggered.  I had to change the code where the formGroup is built to pass in an empty object (instead of an empty string as before), or I get an error from kendo: `Expected value of type Object. See http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/#toc-value-selection.`  (I've also tried an object with: `{ text: '', value: null }`, which doesn't work either)

Typescript:

```
  registrationTypes = [
{ text: 'Professional Engineer', value: 1 },
{ text: 'Professional Surveyor', value: 2 },
{ text: 'Engineer', value: 3 },
{ text: 'Engineer Intern', value: 4 },
{ text: 'Surveyor Intern', value: 5 },
{ text: 'Architect - Individual (ARC)', value: 6 },
{ text: 'Landscape Architect - Individual (ARC)', value: 7 }
  ];

  createFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      registrationType: [{}, Validators.required],
      licenseId: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

Template:

```
<label class="k-form-field">
    <span>Type</span>
    <kendo-dropdownlist id="registrationType" formControlName="registrationType"
        [data]="registrationTypes" [filterable]="false"
        textField="text" valueField="value">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
</label>
```

Comment: Initializing form with `null` works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xyjd3. `null` is an object and is also evaluated to `false`.

Comment: @KarolTrybulec this is the answer, thank you.